# Android With WindowManager View not move down when soft keyboard hide

Tags: android

I'm working with WindowManager for showing popup (myView) with a Service (I can explain why but it's not the subject)

```
layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        layoutParams.packageName = context.getPackageName();
        layoutParams.buttonBrightness = 1f;
        layoutParams.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        layoutParams.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE;

final WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 manager.addView(myView, layoutParams);
```

In my popup there is an `EditText`, when it request focus, automatically keyboard move up and the view do the same.

My problem is, when `backButton` is pressed, automatically keyBoard move down but not my view.
What can I do to make my view back down?